# How to handle more than 10 parameters in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parameters

I am using bash shell on linux and want to use more than 10 parameters in shell script

Comment: Note that having 10 parameters will make it quite confusing.  Perhaps it would be better to use options (e.g. `-a 1` or `--foo=bar`) instead.  See `man getopt`, `man getopts`, and `man bash` for some options for doing that.

Comment: See also: [Why do bash command line arguments after 9 require curly brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318716/why-do-bash-command-line-arguments-after-9-require-curly-brackets)

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Use curly braces to set them off:

```
echo "${10}"
```

Any positional parameter can be saved in a variable to document its use and make later statements more readable:

```
city_name=${10}
```

If fewer parameters are passed then the value at the later positions will be unset.

You can also iterate over the positional parameters like this:

```
for arg
```

or

```
for arg in "$@"
```

or

```
while (( $# > 0 ))    # or [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: Note that ${10} will work in bash, but will limit your portability since many implementations of sh only allow single digit specifications.

Comment: @William: There are some shells that won't accept it, such as the original legacy Bourne shell, but in addition to the shells I listed in another comment (Bash, dash, ksh and zsh), it also works in csh, tcsh and Busybox ash.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `${10}` is defined [by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Comment: Worrying about `${10}` working is only necessary when using very old implementations which are not standard compliant.  Probably only of historical interest...and yet I have yet to ever use it!  I suppose because best practice dictates that 10 arguments is way too many unless they are repeated, in which case you'll iterate over them with `"$@"` rather than enumerating them.

Answer (score 38):

You can have up to 256 parameters from 0 to 255 with:

```
${255}
```

Comment: I think that limit is dependent on the shell. Bash, dash, ksh and zsh don't seem to have it. `sh -c 'echo ${333}' /usr/bin/*`

Comment: My shell comfortably goes up to 2 million `set $(seq 2097152); echo ${2097152}`

Comment: You can run `getconf ARG_MAX` to find out the max number of parameters your system can handle.